# JavaScript Beginner Syntax Errors

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I wrote this program out in plain code but I don't know Javascript well enough to get all the syntax right. I am a beginning programming please help me with corrections to my code. It is currently not running at all. We are still going over loops and it's really giving me trouble. This is for a college class. (I know this isn't formatted properly that's why i'm asking for help)

```
function main() {
alert("Welcome to the program");
var fatGrams = getFatGrams(fatGrams);
var calories = getCalories(fatGrams,calories);
var percentage = caloriesPercentage(fatGrams,calories); 
displayPercentage(percentage); 
}

function getFatGrams(fatGrams) { 
fatGrams = prompt("Enter the number of fat grams in your food item");
while(fatGrams < 0){
  alert("Error, the fat grams cannot be less than 0.");
  fatGrams = prompt("Enter the new number of fat grams.");
 }
return fatGrams;
}

function getCalories(fatGrams,calories) {
calories = prompt("Enter the number of calories in your food item.");
while (calories < 9 || calories > (fatGrams * 9)){
  alert("Error, the calories cannot be less than 9 or exceed the fat    grams * 9");
  calories = prompt("Enter the new number of calories");
}  
return calories;
}

function caloriesPercentage(fatGrams,calories){
percentage = (fatGrams * 9) / calories;
alert("The amount of calories that come from fat is, " + percentage);
return percentage;
}

function displayPercentage(percentage){
  if(percentage < 0.3){
  alert("The food is low in fat.");
 }
  else{
 alert("The food is not too low in fat.");
 }
}

main(); 
alert("End of program");
```

Comment: Remove the `function` keyword from `function getFatGrams(fatGrams);` and others in `main`

Comment: Is there a reason why `displayPercentage` has an empty `else` block... ?

Comment: No there isn't a reason. Should that loop just end with "end if" instead?

Comment: There is no `if.. then` in JS it should be `if(){}else{}`

Comment: `if (percentage < 0.3) { alert("The food is low in fat."); }` That is all you need. No need for `else` and `end if`, and as @me_digvijay mentioned, there is no `then`.

Comment: I'd take a step back and just check out some basic JS tutorials before going too much further--JS isn't BASIC. Once you've done that you'll be a lot further along.

Comment: me_digvijay could you show me what you mean?

Comment: He means that Javascript `if-else` statements are written in the format `if () {} else {}`, e.g. `if (percentage < 0.3) { return percentage; } else { return 0; }`. Javascript has no `end if` and no `then`.

Comment: This looks more like a python, JS and a combination of few other languages.

Comment: I made some corrections, still not running...

Answer (score 2):

Errors in your code :

1. The `function` keyword is not needed to call a function. Remove the keyword `function` before calling a function and simply call the function as `getFatGrams(fatGrams);`
2. You are not passing parameters to `function caloriesPercentage`. Change it to `caloriesPercentage(fatGrams,calories);`
3. The expression for a `while` loop should be enclosed in paranthesis as `while(fatGrams < 0)`.
4. The `OR` should be written as `||`.
5. Use `+` to concatenate 2 string (Or a string and a variable)

   ```
   "The amount of calories that come from fat is, " + percentage
   ```
6. The expression for an `while` should also be enclosed in paranthesis as `if(percentage < 0.3)` and no `then` is needed. The curly brackets of `if` should be closed before `else`.

   ```
   if(percentage < 0.3){
       alert("The food is low in fat.");
   }
   else {
       alert("The food is not too low in fat.");
   }
   ```
7. assign value from `prompt` to variable as

   ```
   fatGrams = prompt("Enter the new number of fat grams.");
   ```

Your final code should look like this :

```
function main() {
  alert("Welcome to the program");
  var fatGrams;
  var calories;
  var percentage;
  getFatGrams(fatGrams);
  getCalories(fatGrams,calories);
  caloriesPercentage(fatGrams,calories); 
  displayPercentage(percentage); 
}

function getFatGrams(fatGrams) { 
  fatGrams = prompt("Enter the number of fat grams in your food item");
  while(fatGrams < 0){
    alert("Error, the fat grams cannot be less than 0.");
    fatGrams = prompt("Enter the new number of fat grams.");
  }
  return fatGrams;
}

function getCalories(fatGrams,calories) {
  calories = prompt("Enter the number of calories in your food item.");
  while (calories < 9 || calories > (fatGrams * 9)){
    alert("Error, the calories cannot be less than 9 or exceed the fat    grams * 9");
    calories = prompt("Enter the new number of calories");
  }
  return calories;
}

function caloriesPercentage(fatGrams,calories){
  percentage = (fatGrams * 9) / calories;
  alert("The amount of calories that come from fat is, " + percentage);
  return percentage;
}

function displayPercentage(percentage){
  if(percentage < 0.3){
    alert("The food is low in fat.");
  }
  else{
    alert("The food is not too low in fat.");
  }
}

main(); 
alert("End of program");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining what the symbols are supposed to be and what they do that's really what I need. I still however can't get it to run...

Answer (score 2):

welcome to the wonderful world of programming!

It looks like you are getting the basics down, let me explain some of the issues you are having with JavaScript. I'm going to use some big words (as will many other experienced developers so get used to them!).

### Function Declaration vs Function Invocation

The very first issue I see with your `main()` function is a confusion about when to use the `function` keyword in JavaScript. You only need to use `function` when you are declaring a function, or in other words when you want to "create a new function." When you declare something, you are creating it, and in JavaScript the `function` keyword is how you declare (aka create) a Function. Here is an example of creating a "named function" in javascript.

```
function addTwo( number ) {
    return number + 2;
}
```

That right there is a "named function" declaration. On a side note, you can also create functions as "expressions" (which would be called a "function expression"). That would look like this

```
var addThree = function( number ) {
  return number + 3;
};
```

Note that in both cases we are creating a function with the `function` keyword.

When you want to use a function, you "invoke" it. This is also referred to as "calling" a function. To call (aka invoke) a function you simply write the function name with parenthesis behind it, passing in any arguments. Function invocation works the same for both named functions and function expressions. So we could invoke the two functions above like so

```
var four = addTwo( 2 );
var five = addThree( 2 );
```

Simply put, only use the `function` keyword to make functions. To call or use a function just put `( argument, otherArg )` at the end of the function name.

### Branching Statements

The next thing I see is that you're missing some parenthesis! JavaScript has a C style syntax so that means you need to put parenthesis around expressions for `if`, `else if`, and `switch` statements. Those keywords I listed are what we call Branching Statements. They allow you to conditionally execute code based on some true or false value, as opposed to Looping Statements that allow you to repeat code based on a true or false value. The structure for an `if .. else` branching statement in JavaScript is as follows.

```
if ( number % 2 === 0 ) {
    number *= 2;
} else if ( number % 3 === 0 ) {
    number *= 3;
} else {
    number += 5;
}
```

For both `if` and `else if` you need to provide an "expression" to branch around. An `else` statement is always executed if none of the `if` or `else if` expressions evaluated to true. The `else` clause is not required so if you don't have any code in your `else` block you can just remove it! It is perfectly fine to have a single if statement like this in your code

```
if ( needsCleanup ) {
    doCleanup();
}
```

Of course it would be ok to have an `else if` clause and no `else` clause, the `else` is always optional. But remember the `else` clause never has an expression so you should never write `()` after a simple `else`.

### Looping Statements

Looping is a big concept that takes a while to master so don't get frustrated or discouraged! In JavaScript we have `for`, `while` and `do while` loops. Just like `if` statements looping statements need an expression, but in this case they need it to know when to stop looping. I'm not going to cover `do while` loops because they are rarely used and can be confusing when just starting out. Simply put, looping statements say: "keep executing this code block until the expression is false." I find it easiest to illustrate this with a `for` loop. For loops are a great way to run a code block a specific number of times. Let's look at an example that adds all the numbers from 1 to 10 with a for loop.

```
var sum = 0;
for ( var i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++ ) {
   sum += i;
}
// sum will be 55
// i will be 11
```

A `for` loop has three expression separated by `;`. The first is for initialization and is only executed before the loop starts (the `var i = 1` part). The second is the condition that is checked before each iteration. The last is an increment operation that is executed at the end of every loop execution. If we were to re-write this for loop as a `while` look it would look like this...

```
var sum = 0;
var i = 1;
while ( i <= 10 ) {
    sum += i;
    i++;
}
```

So you can see the `var i = 1` happens before the loop starts. The `i <= 10` happens before each time the loop runs its body (the part in the `{}`). And the `i++` happens at the end of the loop before it checks `i <= 10` to see if it should keep looping.

### String Concatenation

String concatenation is the process of putting two strings together. In JavaScript the `+` operator does double duty as addition `1 + 1` and string concatenation `'hello' + ' world'`. So when you want to put two strings together you simply add them! If the strings are in variables then you can just "add" them together...

```
var salutation = 'Hello';
var name = 'Kylie';
var greeting = salutation + ', ' + name;

// greeting will be "Hello, Kylie"
```

I hope that clears some things up, if you have any questions please let me know!

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome! I am not a fan so far, trying my best though. :P

Answer (score 1):

Because this IS for a class I am NOT going to give you the answers but instead point out the issues.

Calling a function in Javascript and return a value:

```
var myvalue = myFunction();
```

You have `function...` in your main and need to fix that.

Some functions just return values and thus calling them needs no parameter (like above) others need parameters for the inputs which you have done.

Prompt returns a value and you need to capture that value:

```
var myinputvalue = prompt("enter value");
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Conditionls need to be wrapped in parenthesis when using `while`, `if` etc.

`while (mything < 0){`  Reference; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while

" OR " in a conditional is represented by `||` and an AND by `&&`

NOTE: You can use some on-line tools to work out some of the issues for example paste your code into http://jshint.com/ and it will tell you many of the syntax issues.